# How to reduce Cyclomatic complexity of Switch case statements

Tags: c#

There is an function which has switch case and we need to reduce its CC

```
       string data = string.empty;
       switch (value)
        {
            case "Less than 2 billion":
                data = "0 - 2B";
                break;
            case "2 billion to 10 billion":
                data = "2B - 10B";
                break;
            case "10 billion to 20 billion":
                data = "10B - 20B";
                break;
            case "20 billion to 50 billion":
                data = "20B - 50B";
                break;
            case "Greater than 50 billion":
                data = "> 50B";
                break;
            case "N/A":
                data = "N/A";
                break;
            case "[items] > 0":
                data = string.Empty;
                break;
        }
        return data;
```

Comment: IMHO CC is metric that should serve as a guideline not as a rule. The switch statement gives higher CC but is there really a maintainability problem here?

Comment: But does reduce CC by replacing it with a dictionary truely increase maintainability or is it just reducing CC? In my experience; whenever I have replaced these kind of switch statements with a dictionary lookup the response has been: "I liked the switch statement better". Who is correct about maintainability? The CC metric or the devs that are maintaining it?

Comment: I don't think replacing this with a dictionary makes it any less complex and I think you'd be better off spending your effort elsewhere. One thing that worries me however are the hardcoded strings (e.g. "Less than 2 billion" and "0 - 2B"), these should really be constants for maintainability. FYI you don't need a break on each case if you are just returning data, just do `return "0-2B";`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a dictionary lookup in this case, it would be a little less code and clearer.

Comment: i used Dictionary<string, string> and now CC is 1 but want to know if same function is being called in multiple places then will it hamper performance because in every call it will create Dictionary.

Comment: In most situations you can have the the dictionary as a static member and thus only initializing it once.

Answer (score 2):

Cyclomatic Complexity is *one way* to measure maintainability of code, and help to warn you when there's a sign you're not following good design principles. Rather than evading the error/warning you're getting from cyclomatic complexity with a solution like a dictionary lookup (which has the same maintainability problems), consider whether there's a fundamental design that should change so code like this isn't even necessary.

Presumably the concepts encoded in your strings (e.g. `"Less than 2 billion"`) represent a business-level decision. If that business model changes (maybe you introduce a new layer of specificity), there's some code somewhere else in your code base that will have to change to accommodate that model, right? And if that code changes, then this switch statement will also have to change in order to stay correct, right? The fact that two places in code had to change to accommodate a single Reason For Change implies that you're breaking the Single Responsibility Principle.

One approach could be to put the data mappings you've got here into the same place. Where you might have returned `"Less than 2 billion"` somewhere else in your code, you can now return an object of a type which you define to hold information like this (e.g. `new NumericBucket{FullText = "Less than 2 billion", AbbreviatedText = "0 - 2B"}`).

You may also consider whether these buckets should really be defined in code at all: perhaps they make more sense as configuration, so that if they need to change they can be changed instantly without requiring changes to code. In that case, the `NumericBucket`s could be populated based on configuration in a database or a file somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
private Dictionary<EnumType, Action<param1Type,param2Type,etc> strategies = 
new Dictionary<EnumType, Action<param1Type, param2Type, etc>();
```

...

```
private void LoadDictionary()
{
strategies.Add(enumType.Option1, Method1);
strategies.Add(enumType.Option2, Method2);
...
}
```

...

```
private void Method1(param1Type param, param2Type param2, etc)
{
// your specific logic here
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
public void DoSomethingDependingOnCase(enumType option, param1Type param1, param2Type param2)
{
strategies[option].Invoke(param1,param2,etc);
}
```