# Reduce Switch Case

Tags: c#

I have made a program with a big state machine, with dozens of states.
In each state I just display a message and do a defined action.
I have a very big switch case

```
public int Trigger(actualState)
{
   case 0 :
     return Action0();
   case 1 :
     return Action1();
   case 3 :
     return Action2();


   case 30 :
     return Action30();
}
```

Some of my states could be put together for easier maintainability (for example case 0 to 7 correspond to First challenge, case 8 to 14 to Second challenge, etc)

Do you believe there is an easier way to do than a switch case, for readability and maintainability for instance ?

I have found on Stack Overflow the use of **Dictionary** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763243/how-to-reduce-cyclomatic-complexity-of-switch-case-statements) but I am not sure it. Simplify so much compare to a switch case.

**EDIT**

Is there a possibility to put together case 0 to 8 ? (they don't have the same rsult to return, but something like a function that would say case0to8 and will redirect to another switch case, smaller ?

Comment: You linked an exact duplicate into your question. Just because you don't feel the answer is correct, doesn't make it any less so.

Comment: @NicolasNicolas read Diego Salas's answer. He has everything you need.

Comment: If you mean by "correspond to First challange" that they call the same method then you could do something like this: `case 0:  case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4: case 5: case 6: case 7: return Action1();`

Comment: Is there a possibility to put together case 0 to 8 ? (they don't have the same rsult to return, but something like a function that would say case0to8 and will redirect to another switch case, smaller ?